# Why doesn't Ubuntu/Thunderbird save my PGP key?

Tags: password, encryption, thunderbird, pgp

I installed Thunderbird and followed the instructions from:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto
to set up PGP.

First it worked, but after restarting my system the next day, I wasn't able to open encrypted mails. I added my friends the public key again, but nothing. I discovered that all added key were gone. My own key is not saved in Ubuntu's password and keys app any more. what happened? What can I do now?

If it matters, I didn't upload my public key to any servers.
I am new to the Ubuntu and IT world. Grateful you for helpful answers.

Comment: Maybe I was not successful with installation from following point on:

Set your key as the default key by entering this line in your ~/.bash_profile (along with any other environment variables to be exported). 
export GPGKEY=D8FC66D2
Now restart the gpg-agent and set the relevant environment variable.
killall -q gpg-agent
eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)
export GPGKEY=D8FC66D2

But it had worked first. What can I do now?

Comment: I was not successful with installation from following point on:

Set your key as the default key by entering this line in your ~/.bash_profile (along with any other environment variables to be exported). 
export GPGKEY=D8FC66D2
Now restart the gpg-agent and set the relevant environment variable.
killall -q gpg-agent
eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)
export GPGKEY=D8FC66D2

But it had worked first. I cant remember if i skipped. I just setup Thunderbird and Enigmail after that. And it worked. Even after restarting the system. But only for one day... What can I do now?

Comment: Please do not add important additional information in comments, people are likely to overlook them there. Comments may also get deleted for various reasons without notice. You should [edit] your question to provide the information instead. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way to do this would be to use [Enigmail](https://www.enigmail.net/).

Just install it and follow the instructions.
Quoting your link:

> Thunderbird
>
> Thunderbird supports OpenPGP through the enigmail plugin.
>
> Enigmail is available in the "Main" repository.
>
> sudo apt-get install enigmail
>
> Configure OpenPGP support in Thunderbird under Enigmail->Preferences and add under GnuPG executable path. The path for GnuPG is /usr/bin/gpg.

You don't need to configure anything. No need to mess it up.